# How to disable Siri?

Tags: ios, siri

I [disabled it in Siri & Search settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcClf.jpg) and also [in Youtube-specific Siri settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0itu4.jpg). However, the damn thing pops out every few sec when I’m watching Youtube in my headphones that also have a mic. I even muted the headphone mic, to no avail.

How do I get rid of Siri for good? Preferably uninstall it completely, but if that’s not possible then at least completely disable it?

Comment: What version of iOS are you on, and what model/type of device?

Comment: @benwiggy, iOS 14.6, iPad Air 2.